# Convert List<int?> to List<int>

Tags: c#, int, nullable

Suppose, I have a list of `Nullable Integer's` & I want to convert this list into `List<int>` which contains only values.

Can you please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Filter out the `null` values, get the numbers using `Value` property and put them into a list using `ToList`:

```
yourList.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

You can also use `Cast`

```
yourList.Where(x => x != null).Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Comment: What if. i want to cast all property named `UserId` in a list to integer list using `Cast<int>()` possible ?

Comment: Cast also resolves issue with the new null management in .NET6

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
List<int> newList = originalList.Where(v => v != null)
                                .Select(v => v.Value)
                                .ToList();
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 var numbers1 = new List<int?>() { 1, 2, null};
 var numbers2 = numbers1.Where(n => n.HasValue).Select(n => n.Value).ToList();
```